# Ruby Array Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I am currently trying to create a ruby algorithm to execute the following:

```
l = Array.new
```

Given array is text in the form of an array and has three manifests each titled Section No. 1, Section No. 2, Section No. 3 respectively.

1. Put the entire text in one string by looping through the array(l) and adding each line to the one big string each time.
2. Split the string using the split method and the key word "Section No." This will create an array with each element being one section of the text.
3. Loop through this new array to create files for each element.

So far I have the following:

```
a = l.join ''
b = Array.new
b = a.split ("Section No.")`
```

How would I go writing the easiest method to the third part?
Should only be about 2-3 lines.

Output would be the creation of three files each named after the manifest titles.

"Complex Version"

```
file_name = "Section" 
section_number = "1"

new_text = File.open(file_name + section_number, 'w')
i = 0 
n= 1
while i < l.length 
    if (l[i]!= "SECTION") and (l[i+1]!= "No")
    new_text.puts l[i]
    i = i + 1
    else 
        new_text.close
        section_number = (section_number.to_i +1).to_s
        new_text = File.open(file_name + section_number, "w")
        new_text.puts(l[i])
        new_text.puts(l[i+1])
        i=i+2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your most basic question, you could probably get away with:

```
sections.each_with_index do |section, index|
  File.open("section_#{index}.txt", 'w') { |file| file.print section }
end
```

Here's an alternate solution:

```
input_string = "This should be your manifest string"
starting_string = "Section No."
copy_input_string = input_string.clone
sections = []
while(copy_input_string.length > 0)
  index_of_next_start = copy_input_string.index(starting_string, starting_string.length) || copy_input_string.length
  sections.push(copy_input_string.slice!(0...index_of_next_start))
end
sections.each_with_index do |section, index|
  File.open("section_#{index}.txt", 'w') { |file| file.print section }
end
```

Comment: When you use `sections.each` where did you derive sections? I'm pretty new to Ruby. Is it a method or is it simply because of the fact that I'm trying to make "Section No"
AKA is that flexible to anything?

Comment: No, it's just what I would have named your variable b in order to be descriptive of what the contents were.

Comment: So after running the program I just get 1 file called "Section_0" with all three manifests in it. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: `puts b.size` will give you the size of the array. Did the file split actually divide the file into sections?

Comment: It says 1 so I'm assuming no. Is there a better way to split it up into sections using the keyword?

Comment: Can you explain your inputs a little better? What kind of starting input do you have? If you're starting off with a string that has multiple occurrences of "Section No." that you're using to split the arrays up with, then you should probably use a slightly different approach than split, involving scanning the text for instances of "Section No." and then splitting substrings up from there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! I'm incompetent in Ruby and have no idea how to go about that. 
The input is essentially a collection of manifestos each titled "Section No." followed by the consecutive number. 
I'm trying to split these sections up and save them according to their number.

Comment: See one possible solution in the edited body. This is a typical approach in any programming language.

Comment: The edited solution is similar to an algorithm I had written first to accomplish the listed tasks. I decided to go for this basic approach as I had thought it got too complex. 
One main issue I had with my complex version was that it failed to go to the `else` and I just couldn't figure out why. I've added my complex version to my original post, could you take a look at it and see if you could debug it?

It also runs into the issue of it just adding all the sections into one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
b.each_with_index(1) do |text, index|
  File.write "section_#{index}.txt", text
end
```

Answer (score 0):

create string s by putting a space between each string in l

```
s = l.join ' '
```

split on 'Section No.' - note that 'Section No.' no longer appears in a

```
a = s.split('Section No.')
```

throw away the part before the first section

```
a = a[1..-1]
```

create the files

```
a.each do |section|
  File.open('Section' + section.strip[0], 'w') do |file_handle|
    file_handle.puts section
  end
end
```